# SharePoint Intranet - DNS pointing here?

Tags: sharepoint-online, domain, intranet, dns

**Background:**

We are currently using a very old intranet that is hosted on one of our internal servers. I've designed a SharePoint Online intranet that looks a lot better, plus it'll feature a lot more communication and collaboration. We want to start using the new SPO intranet but the main obstacle to adoptability.

**Scenario:**

When users in our organization type in, for example, gnet into their browser of choice, they are automatically redirected to http://gnet/. This provides an extreme ease of access which is great. However, if users were to access our SPO site, they'd need to login to their O365 accounts.

Is there a way to discontinue the old gnet, use that same domain/URL and redirect them into our SharePoint Online intranet? I've looked at several solutions online and couldn't find anything concrete. The alternate access mapping feature isn't available for SPO from what i've discovered. Would anyone have any ideas?? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stand up a service, often this is done in IIS, to use a redirect from http://gnet to the desired URL of choice, for example https://gnet.sharepoint.com.

[HTTP Redirects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/)

There are other options (you could use Apache, nginx, Azure Web Site, etc.) to do this, so don't feel restricted to IIS.

Comment: Thank you for your response Trevor.

After asking this question in other discussion forums, some suggest using the CNAME method?I've tried researching some of the responses I've received and can't seem to come to a conclusion. I know CNAME involves utilizing the DNS, but I don't believe HTTP redirect does? 

Are there any pros vs. cons you're aware of?

Thanks